# SQL Server: drop a FK constraint, which is not foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I am using SQL Server 2008 and its Management Studio. I am doing a web project, which has a tool to automate the tables/relationships creation.

My web project reveals this error:

> Unsuccessful: alter table Tester add constraint FK_c6c4bf4s2rvp56a32nnruww2b foreign key (game) references Game
>
> Column 'Game.id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Tester.game' in foreign key 'FK_c6c4bf4s2rvp56a32nnruww2b'

However, when I ran the following in the management studio:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tester DROP CONSTRAINT FK_c6c4bf4s2rvp56a32nnruww2b
```

I get the following:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   'FK_c6c4bf4s2rvp56a32nnruww2b' is not a constraint.
>   Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

I am confused. What type of constraint is `FK_c6c4bf4s2rvp56a32nnruww2b`?

How can I remove it?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Your problem is you cannot create an FK constraint between two tables if they don't have the same data type. Your application needs to consider that. Frankly it is a poor idea to have a design that allows users to create database objects at all. Users don't understand database design and invariably create garbage which wil harm performance and have data integrity issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no such constraint**!

The first error clearly says that it **could NOT** create that constraint since the datatypes of those two columns involved (`Game.Id` and `Tester.Game`) do not match.

What you should do is check how you're creating your FK constraint that leads to that first error - and **explicitly** give that FK constraint a meaningful name!

Comment: The problematic constraint was created by the automation tool. Anyway, I can list all constraints of a database?

Comment: @curious1: sorry - typo - it should be `SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys` - this catalog view shows all foreign key constraints defined in your database

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
 sp_help [table_name]
```

to get all the foreign key constraints.

When you get the foreign key constraints on the table. Drop them by writing something like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] DROP CONSTRAINT [Foreign_FK]
```

Comment: I tried "sp_help dbo.Tester" and got an error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: Thanks. I ran it and it produces nice results. However, I can only see the PK key. The constraint in question is not listed.

Comment: No. I am unable to see the problematic constraint.

Comment: @curious1:- There is no such standard foreign key contraint which you have mentioned.

Comment: Rahul, thanks so much for your help too. You are right, there is no such constraint. Best.

Comment: Both of replies point me to the same direction and I was simply blinded. The reply was posted earlier than yours. I did vote for your post. Best!